# Overriding properties in javamoney.properties?

Tags: java, jsr354, java-money

Using the new 1.0 version of [JavaMoney API](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api) with the [reference implementation](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri) we try to stop the resource-loader from loading other ExchangeRateProvider by overriding javamoney.properties.

```
{1}conversion.default-chain=MY-PROVIDER
# Turn off loading of the default Moneta ExchangeRateProviders.
{1}load.ECBCurrentRateProvider.type=NEVER
{1}load.ECBHistoric90RateProvider.type=NEVER
{1}load.ECBHistoricRateProvider.type=NEVER
{1}load.IMFRateProvider.type=NEVER
{1}load.AbstractECBRateProvider=NEVER
```

However, the log tells me they are still being loaded:

```
jun 19, 2015 8:27:58 AM  org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.AbstractECBRateProvider newDataLoaded
INFO: Loaded ECBCurrentRateProvider exchange rates for days:1
```

From the LoaderService interface 'NEVER' triggers loading the local resource (and not the remote), but I've also tried 'LAZY'.

```
public interface LoaderService {

/**
 * Platform RI: The update policy defines how and when the
 * {@link LoaderService} tries to update the local cache with newest version of
 * the registered data resources, accessing the configured remote
 * {@link URI}s. By default no remote connections are done (
 * {@link UpdatePolicy#NEVER} ).
 *
 * @author Anatole Tresch
 */
public enum UpdatePolicy {
    /**
     * The resource will never be updated from remote, only the fallback URL
     * will be evaluated.
     */
    NEVER,
    /**
     * The resource will be loaded automatically from remote only once on
     * startup.
     */
    ONSTARTUP,
    /**
     * The resource will be loaded automatically from remote only once, when
     * accessed the first time.
     */
    LAZY,
    /**
     * The resource should be regularly reloaded based on a schedule.
     */
    SCHEDULED
}
...
```

What we've noted is that in the constructor of the ExchangeProviders in org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert, there is a call to loader.loadDataAsync:

```
AbstractECBRateProvider(ProviderContext context) {
    super(context);
    saxParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    saxParserFactory.setValidating(false);
    LoaderService loader = Bootstrap.getService(LoaderService.class);
    loader.addLoaderListener(this, getDataId());
    loader.loadDataAsync(getDataId());
}
```

This is the same as for case 'ONSTARTUP' in the method [registerData](http://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/org/javamoney/moneta/1.0/moneta-1.0-javadoc.jar/-/org/javamoney/moneta/internal/loader/DefaultLoaderService.html#registerData-java.lang.String-org.javamoney.moneta.spi.LoaderService.UpdatePolicy-java.util.Map-org.javamoney.moneta.spi.LoaderService.LoaderListener-java.net.URI-java.net.URI...-) in [DefaultLoaderService](http://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/org/javamoney/moneta/1.0/moneta-1.0-javadoc.jar/-/org/javamoney/moneta/internal/loader/DefaultLoaderService.html):

```
switch (updatePolicy) {
        case NEVER:
            loadDataLocal(resourceId);
            break;
        case ONSTARTUP:
            loadDataAsync(resourceId);
            break;
        case SCHEDULED:
            addScheduledLoad(res);
            break;
        case LAZY:
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Could this be a reason that it is loaded no matter what I put in my javamoney.properties?

How do we turn off the other ExchangeRateProviders altogether? We only want to use our custom [ExchangeRateProvider](http://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/javax/money/money-api/1.0/money-api-1.0-javadoc.jar/-/javax/money/convert/ExchangeRateProvider.html).

Answer (score 5):

Looks we have an issue here. Can you please file a Jira issue in our java.net/javamoney project (and check if this issue was already filed :) ). We plan to publish a patch release of the ri next days, so we may fix this as well.

Thanks a lot!
Anatole

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have filed a Jira: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVAMONEY-131.

Comment: Jira link is outdated, please see this ticket https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/issues/170